# Lifetime Analysis with Exponential Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm considering a situation measuring whether or not a certain device fails using a relatively simple model. Let $T$ be an exponential rv with mean $\mu$. For $t < T$, the hazard rate $h(t) = c_1$, and for $t \geq T $, the hazard rate $h(t) = c_2$, given $c_2 > c_1$. I'm trying to find the expected lifetime and the probability that the lifetime is shorter than $T$ (implying the device fails because of something else other than what I'm analyzing).

For the expected lifetime, we have two pdfs and thus two expectations.

1. If $t < T$, then $f(t)$ (the survivor function) is $c_1e^{-c_1t}$, so $E[L]$ is just $\frac{1}{c_1}$.
2. If $t \geq T$, then $f(t)$ is $c_2e^{-c_2t}$, so $E[L]$ is just $\frac{1}{c_2}$.

This seems right to me due to the memoryless property of the exponential (in that, it doesn't matter how long the component has lasted, it's rate of failure given that it's lasted this far is still going to be the same as if it had come right out of the production line), except when we pass a certain point in which the rate of hazard itself changes.

As for the second part, I'm not entirely sure how to start with it.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this correctly: 1.  There is a particular kind of fault, which occurs at a time that is exponentially distributed with mean $\mu$.  2.  This fault does not cause the immediate failure of the device, but prior to the fault, the device fails at a constant rate $c_1$, and after the fault, the device fails at a constant rate $c_2$, with $c_2 > c_1$.  Is that all right?  If so, what is it that you would like to know?

Comment: "For the expected lifetime, we have two pdfs and thus two expectations" Huh? As far as I know, each random variable has one expectation, not two. In the present case, considering some independent exponential lifetime $L_i$ with parameter $c_i$, it seems that one considers the random variable $$L=L_1\mathbf 1_{L_1<T}+(T+L_2)\mathbf 1_{L_1>T}.$$ If this is indeed the model you have in mind, then $$E(L)=\frac1{c_1}-\left(\frac1{c_1}-\frac1{c_2}\right)e^{-c_1T}.$$

Comment: @Did $T$ is itself exponentially distributed. (I made the same mistake.)

Comment: @Ian Right, this had escaped me. Then the expectation in my previous comment is $E(L\mid T)$ and, integrating with respect to the distribution of $T$, one gets $$E(L)=\frac1{c_1}-\left(\frac1{c_1}-\frac1{c_2}\right)\frac{1}{1+\mu c_1}=\frac{1+\mu c_2}{1+\mu c_1}\,\frac{1}{c_2}.$$

Comment: @BrianTung Sorry if I phrased it badly, I'm just picking up survival analysis. 

1. There is a fault that occurs at a time $T$ that is exponentially distributed with mean $\mu$ - this is correct. When this fault occurs, the device dies.
2. If this fault occurs, the device is dead. The rate of it occurring before some time $T$ has a constant hazard rate $c_1$, and after some time $T$, it has a higher hazard rate $c_2$. 
3. $P(L < T)$ is the probability that this device dies before something else happens - instead of a transistor blow out, it just dies of a faulty motherboard or something.

Comment: @Did There are two different hazard rates, and thus two different survivor functions, for different times relative to $T$. If $t < T$, then $f(t)$, the survivor function, is $c_1e^{-c_1t}$, and if $t \geq T$, then $f(t)$, the survivor function, is $c_2e^{-c_2t}$. I'm not sure if the expectation of a lifetime is some sort of convolution of these two, though. Most of the notation I'm using, I learned from the first pages of this [explanation](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7.pdf).

Comment: @genap: I think we're converging here.  My answer, Ian's answer, and Did's answer in his last comment produce the same result.  The same basic approach is involved in each answer, although they are presented differently.  Hopefully the three of them in conjunction will suffice.  Incidentally, $P(L < T) = \mu c_1/(1+\mu c_1)$.

Comment: @Did I think I'm starting to make sense of your answer, but I don't see how you got the latter half of your conditional expectation.

Comment: @Did Actually, I don't know if I understand any of your answer, but it's the one that's most in line with what I'm studying (although the others were all excellent, albeit out of my range). I'd really appreciate it if you could explain a bit further.

Comment: You mean, how to compute $E(L\mid T)=E(L_1\mathbf 1_{L_1<T}\mid T)+E((T+L_2)\mathbf 1_{L_1>T}\mid T)$? Which part escapes you?

Comment: @Did Yeah, I think once I get that I should be able to integrate through the conditionals to get the expected lifetime. I know that $L_1$ is $e^{-c_1t}$, and I think your indicator random variable is just $c_1$ for $L_1<T$, so this equals $\frac{1}{c_1}$, which I get. But I don't know what the second indicator variable is (I have a hunch it's $1-L_1<T$), nor do I know how to calculate $T + L_2$ and it's expectation. Sorry if my questions seem amateurish, this is my first attempt at hazard rates.

Comment: For every event $A$, $\mathbf 1_A$ is defined by $\mathbf 1_A(\omega)=1$ if $\omega$ is in $A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(\omega)=0$ otherwise. Thus, for example, $$E(L_1\mathbf 1_{L_1<t})=\int_0^txf_{L_1}(x)dx.$$

Comment: @Did I think I meant that the expectation of the indicator variable was just the probability of $L_1<T$, which is $c_1$.

Comment: Actually, $P(L_1<t)=1-e^{-c_1t}$ and  $P(L_1<T)=\frac{\mu c_1}{1+\mu c_1}$, not $c_1$.

Comment: @Did Ahh, I guess I'm even further lost than I expected. I think this might have something to do with my knowledge of indicator random variables. Why is $E(L_1\mathbf 1_{L_1<t})=\int_0^txf_{L_1}(x)dx$ true?

Comment: Because $\mathbf 1_{L_1<t}$ is defined as I explained hence one restricts the integral giving the expectation to $(-\infty,t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convenient perspective which I think is physically natural is to consider this as a continuous time Markov chain on three states. You have a state with one hazard rate, a state with another hazard rate, and a state where the device has failed. Call these $1,2,3$. Then the overall process is a continuous time Markov chain with generator matrix

$$G=\begin{bmatrix} 
-\frac{1}{\mu} - c_1 & \frac{1}{\mu} & c_1 \\
0 & -c_2 & c_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

In this form, you are asking for the expected time to hit state $3$ starting from state $1$, which is a classic problem. The solution is given by the first component of the vector $u$ where

$$\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{\mu}-c_1 & \frac{1}{\mu} & c_1 \\
0 & -c_2 & c_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} u = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

When I solve this I get $\frac{1+\frac{1}{\mu c_2}}{\frac{1}{\mu}+c_1}=\frac{\mu+\frac{1}{c_2}}{1+c_1 \mu}$. For a sanity check, if $\mu$ is large this becomes $\frac{1}{c_1}$, for $\mu=0$ this becomes $\frac{1}{c_2}$. Both are expected.

In formulating this I am introducing some independence assumptions which I do not think you have fully specified, so they may not be justified. Still, it seems like a natural approach.

Comment: I found this to be the most helpful (intuitively), although Did's approach (which I finally got) was the most relevant for my level of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have two states: $B$ (for before the fault) and $A$ (for after the fault).  After the fault, the time to failure is simply $t_A = 1/c_2$.

Before the fault, you leave state $B$ at a combined rate $c_1+1/\mu$, and so the time to leave state $B$ is $1/(c_1+1/\mu)$.  At that point, with probability $c_1/(c_1+1/\mu)$, you fail immediately, while with probability $1/[\mu(c_1+1/\mu)]$, you proceed to state $A$.  Thus, the time to failure in state $B$ is

$$
t_B = \frac{1}{c_1+1/\mu} + \frac{t_A}{\mu(c_1+1/\mu)}
    = \frac{1+\mu c_2}{c_2(1+\mu c_1)}
$$

ETA: If all you know is that the machine is currently running (in particular, you do not know how long it has been running, or which state it is currently in), one can compute an unconditional expected lifetime as follows: A machine that is in state $B$ transitions to state $A$ at rate $1/\mu$, while a machine in state $A$ "transitions to state $B$" (i.e., is replaced upon failure) at rate $c_2$.  Therefore, if you watch machines in the long run, you will expect to see them in state $B$ with probability

$$
p_B = \frac{\mu c_2}{1+\mu c_2}
$$

and in state $A$ with probability

$$
p_A = \frac{1}{1+\mu c_2}
$$

and then the unconditional expected remaining lifetime is

$$
L_{residual} = p_B t_B + p_A t_A
$$